# VB.NET Windows Forms for each space in string

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

Hy, i have this code

```
Dim RandomNumber As New Random()
Dim msg As String = "My name is Nick from Neptune"
For each space as char in msg
msg = msg.replace(" ", RandomNumber.Next(0, 33))
Next
```

But it does not work.
Can someone help me?
In the end the string should look like this :

```
My12name455is22Nick88from66Neptune
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it to work, my apologies:

```
Option Infer On

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim RandomNumber As New Random()
    Dim msg As String = "My name is Nick from Neptune"
    Dim newmessage As String = ""
    Dim d = msg.Split(" ").ToList()

    For Each t In d
        newmessage = newmessage & Convert.ToString(t) & RandomNumber.[Next](0, 33).ToString()
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(newmessage)
End Sub
```

End Module

[image]

Comment: @KreepN Your's is a lot more elegant than mine. I think your problem is that Vb does not have a var try using Object instead.

Comment: Fixed it. I write mainly in c#, so it was an honest mistake.

Comment: Thanks to all of you who helped me !!! Thanks KreepN , thanks Mark Hall ! It is working THANKS! I have used KreepN solution :d Thanks again, i was looking for an answer for 3 day and finaly found one.Sorry for my English.

Comment: Glad I could help. Your English is actually pretty good! I got what you were trying to do without having to read it more than once. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with what you have written. The main one is that the Message.Replace method will replace all of the spaces in your string with the first Random Number generated. Try splitting the string where the spaces are, then rejoining them with your random numbers in between. Something like this.

```
Dim RandomNumber As New Random()
Dim msg As String = "My name is Nick from Neptune"
Dim temp = msg.Split(CChar(" "))
Dim first As Boolean = True

For Each s As String In temp
    If first Then
        msg = s
    Else
        msg = msg + RandomNumber.Next(0, 33).ToString + s
    End If
    first = False
Next
```

Comment: The second loop should be a for each loop (because you don’t need the index here). The first loop can then be *merged* into the second once you introduce a boolean variable that checkes whether we’re on the first (or last) iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Mark Hall for your fast answer

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are correct. It looks a lot better on the eyes

Comment: @Mark But now it’s inefficient because it has to perform one string comparison per loop. You can instead use a variable `first` (that is set to `False` on the first loop run) and *prefix* all non-first fragments by a random number.